# Efficient algorithm to find all 4-subsets of N points forming a square with no other points inside

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, algorithms, computational-geometry

I'm looking for an algorithm (or any useful resources) to solve the following problem:

> Given a set of $N$ distinct points on a plane, find all the ways to choose $4$ of those points that are the vertices of a square and none of the other points in your set lie inside that square.

I have proved that there are at most $4N$ such squares, and I have an $O(N^2 \log N)$ algorithm to find them all. I'm not too concerned about whether the definition of *inside* includes points on the edge of a square.

Comment: I modified the body, but I can't think of any extra info that would clarify the task. What are you confused about? The problem statement seems clear to me.

Comment: I'm guessing $O(N^2\log N)$ is the best you can do. You need to choose two points, then search for the other two. I don't have a proof though.

Comment: No point can be a vertex of more than four squares with disjoint interiors, so that $4N$ is a generous upper bound on the number of such squares that can be formed.  Is it your purpose to form a tighter upper bound, or to efficiently identify the squares (or perhaps both)?

Comment: To efficiently identify the squares, though I'd be interested in a tighter upper bound too as that may help lead to a method of efficiently identifying the squares. Thanks

Comment: You can immediately remove the factor four from your upper bound because this way of counting counts each square four times (once for each vertex used).  The upper bound $N$ on number of squares (without points in the interior) is asymptotically tight in the sense that placing $(n+1)^2$ points in a uniform Cartesian grid produces $n^2$ of the allowable squares, so ratio of squares to points tends to $1$ as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: @hardmath - sorry to say the Delaunay Triangulation might not generate all the necessary edges for squares, so it'll be impossible to produce *all* squares by the edge removal process. Some diagonals will need to be flipped, and I don't know how to do that systematically

Comment: @HEKTO:  The (ordinary metric) Voronoi diagram allows us to find the largest empty *disk* inside the convex hull of a point set.  This in turn gives a bound on the size of the largest empty square to be found (not necessarily one with vertices drawn from the point set), so it supplies a measure of the *scale* over which searches for empty squares formed by the vertices need to be done.